# Finding coordinates of the pareto corners of a N x M array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I have the following 90 x 2 array `a` where the first column is the x, second column is y values.

```
array([[17.22      , 18.46366161],
       [19.68      , 18.46366161],
       [18.45      , 20.5940841 ],
       [17.22      , 22.7245066 ],
       [22.14      , 18.46366161],
       [20.91      , 20.5940841 ],
       [19.68      , 22.7245066 ],
       [17.22      ,  9.94197164],
       [23.37      , 20.5940841 ],
       [22.14      , 22.7245066 ],
       [19.68      ,  9.94197164],
       [18.45      , 12.07239413],
       [17.22      , 14.20281662],
       [ 9.84      , 18.46366161],
       [ 8.61      , 20.5940841 ],
       [22.14      ,  9.94197164],
       [20.91      , 12.07239413],
       [19.68      , 14.20281662],
       [18.45      , 16.33323912],
       [12.3       , 18.46366161],
       [11.07      , 20.5940841 ],
       [ 9.84      , 22.7245066 ],
       [23.37      , 12.07239413],
       [22.14      , 14.20281662],
       [20.91      , 16.33323912],
       [14.76      , 18.46366161],
       [13.53      , 20.5940841 ],
       [12.3       , 22.7245066 ],
       [ 9.84      ,  9.94197164],
       [ 8.61      , 12.07239413],
       [23.37      , 16.33323912],
       [15.99      , 20.5940841 ],
       [14.76      , 22.7245066 ],
       [12.3       ,  9.94197164],
       [11.07      , 12.07239413],
       [ 9.84      , 14.20281662],
       [ 8.61      , 16.33323912],
       [14.76      ,  9.94197164],
       [13.53      , 12.07239413],
       [12.3       , 14.20281662],
       [11.07      , 16.33323912],
       [15.99      , 12.07239413],
       [14.76      , 14.20281662],
       [13.53      , 16.33323912],
       [15.99      , 16.33323912],
       [18.45      , 17.75352078],
       [20.91      , 17.75352078],
       [19.68      , 19.88394327],
       [18.45      , 22.01436576],
       [23.37      , 17.75352078],
       [22.14      , 19.88394327],
       [20.91      , 22.01436576],
       [19.68      , 24.14478826],
       [ 8.61      , 17.75352078],
       [23.37      , 22.01436576],
       [22.14      , 24.14478826],
       [19.68      , 11.3622533 ],
       [18.45      , 13.49267579],
       [11.07      , 17.75352078],
       [ 9.84      , 19.88394327],
       [ 8.61      , 22.01436576],
       [22.14      , 11.3622533 ],
       [20.91      , 13.49267579],
       [19.68      , 15.62309828],
       [13.53      , 17.75352078],
       [12.3       , 19.88394327],
       [11.07      , 22.01436576],
       [ 9.84      , 24.14478826],
       [23.37      , 13.49267579],
       [22.14      , 15.62309828],
       [15.99      , 17.75352078],
       [14.76      , 19.88394327],
       [13.53      , 22.01436576],
       [12.3       , 24.14478826],
       [ 9.84      , 11.3622533 ],
       [ 8.61      , 13.49267579],
       [17.22      , 19.88394327],
       [15.99      , 22.01436576],
       [14.76      , 24.14478826],
       [12.3       , 11.3622533 ],
       [11.07      , 13.49267579],
       [ 9.84      , 15.62309828],
       [17.22      , 24.14478826],
       [14.76      , 11.3622533 ],
       [13.53      , 13.49267579],
       [12.3       , 15.62309828],
       [17.22      , 11.3622533 ],
       [15.99      , 13.49267579],
       [14.76      , 15.62309828],
       [17.22      , 15.62309828]])
```

I am trying to get the pareto corners of this array:

Coordinate 1 : min x + 1, max y,
Coordinate 2 : max x - 1, max y,
Coordinate 3 : min x + 1, min y,
Coordinate 4 : max x - 1, min y,
Coordinate 5 : min x, max y-2,
Coordinate 6 : max x, max y-2,
Coordinate 7 : min x, min y+2,
Coordinate 8 : max x, min y+2,

I have been able to get this with `corners = a[::a.shape[0]-1, ::a.shape[1]-1]`. But this doesnt work on this particular set of array and potentially further 2D arrays.

Any advise?

Comment: By "corners", do you mean the first and last row? Is this always for 2D arrays, or for arrays with more dimensions as well?

Comment: I edited the original post, perhaps the more correct term is Pareto corner since it's not technically just min and max of x and y - hope this makes sense